# Session["<delegate>"] causes some variables content to be lost

Tags: asp.net, session

I use a delegate in an ASP.NET site.
I use Session[""] to save this delegate's value.
When invoking it, it calls the correct method BUT inside the invoked method body, all of the variables have have values from a prior state.
When I call the method directly (without using the delegate), there are no problems.

I have written and tested this dummy code that illustrates the problem in a (more) comprehensive way:

```
namespace WebApplication_test_update_controls
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public delegate void My_delegate();

        public string str;
        public int age;
        My_delegate del1;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack) //first load
            {
                str = "postback value";
                age = 1;
                del1 = LB_Add_Text;
                TextBox1.Text = "fennec postback";

                Session["str"] = str;
                Session["age"] = age;     
                Session["del1"] = del1;
            }

            if(IsPostBack)
            {
                del1 = (My_delegate)Session["del1"];
                str = (string) Session["str"];
                age = (int) Session["age"];

            }
        }

protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            str = "Value Button event";
            age = 10;
            TextBox1.Text = "fennec Button event";



            //Call of the method without using the delegate, LB_Add_Text is executed with correct values
            LB_Add_Text();

           //!!!Call of the method using the delegate, LB_Add_Text is executed with INCORRECT values!!!
            del1();

             //I explicitally point del1 to LB_Add_Text again (although it seems to already point there looking at debugger
             del1 = LB_Add_Text;

            //then B_Add_Text is executed with correct values this time
            del1();


        }


        public void LB_Add_Text()
        {
            ListBox3.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
        }

 }
}
```

As you can see in the comments, 
all values are stored in Session after first PageLoad and retrieved after postbacks (age, str and the delegate del1).

When I click a button, I set new values to age and str. Debugger shows that del1 still points to LB_Add_Text (so apparently correctly retrieved from Session["del1"] after postback.

I call LB_Add_Text directly : everything works fine, it uses the expected values:

```
   str = "Value Button event";
   age = 10;
   TextBox1.Text = "fennec Button event";
```

then I call the delegate (supposed to do the same) : It does not use the expected values. It correctly calls LB_Add_Text but uses the values retrieved from Session:

```
str = "postback value";
                age = 1;
                del1 = LB_Add_Text;
                TextBox1.Text = "fennec postback";
```

Lastly, I explicitally re-point del1 to LB_Add_Text

```
del1 = LB_Add_Text;
```

, and I invoke it again: then everything works as expected and LB_Add_Text is called with the expected variables values :

```
str = "Value Button event";
   age = 10;
   TextBox1.Text = "fennec Button event";
```

I have the feeling that the whole issue comes from:

```
del1 = (My_delegate)Session["del1"];
```

that somehow does not behave as I would expect, and does not only stores/retrieve the delegate signature.

Can you gurus shed light on what I missed?

Thx in advance.

Comment: You are not updating the session values when you update values.

Comment: I don't think it s the main problem, even if I do, the problem persists.
Furthermore, notice that the problem also occurs with a control's text which is not supposed to lose its content after postbacks (TextBox1.Text)

Comment: Anyone got a suggestion here?

Comment: Nobody who had an idea about this one?